# truffle won't run tests while initializing a global contract instance

Tags: contract-development, truffle, contract-debugging, truffle-test

I am testing my smart contract in truffle. I need to declare some global variables hence I did so outside 'it'.

I also tried declaring a global contract instance that I can use in all test cases.
Though when I do so, none of the test cases are executed.

Consider this test script:

```
const MFT= artifacts.require('MFT');

contract("MFT", async (accounts) => {


let instance = await MFT.deployed();
let owner = accounts[0];

it("should be deployed by owner", async () => {

    let _onwer = await instance.getOwner.call();
    assert.equal(_onwer , owner);
});

});
```

The output that I get is:

```
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.0+commit.1d4f565a.Emscripten.clang



  0 passing (1ms)
```

But when i do not initialize my instance outside the test case and do that within the test case, it works!

Consider the following test script:

```
const MFT= artifacts.require('MFT');

contract("MFT", async (accounts) => {


let instance;
let owner = accounts[0];

it("should be deployed by owner", async () => {
    instance = = await MFT.deployed();
    let _onwer = await instance.getOwner.call();
    assert.equal(_onwer , owner);
});

});
```

When I run this, i get the following output:

```
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.0+commit.1d4f565a.Emscripten.clang



  Contract: MFT
    √ should be deployed by owner (43ms)


  1 passing (87ms)
```

What am i missing?

Comment: In your first example (the one which doesn't work) - the symbol `UBBI` is not defined anywhere. What exactly were you expecting to happen or hoping to achieve here???

Comment: BTW, `contract` takes and executes a function, not an async function, so you may as well get rid of that `async` up there.

Comment: It can. Truffle documentation has it.

Answer (score 0):

To initialize something before running any test you can use `before()`. You pass a function that it will execute previously to any test.

```
contract('MFT', (accounts) => {
    let instance;
    let owner;

    before(async() => {
        instance = await MFT.deployed();
        owner = accounts[0];
    });

    it("should be deployed by owner", async () => {
        let _onwer = await instance.getOwner.call();
        assert.equal(_onwer , owner);
    });
})
```